# Firebase list permission is being checked when adding a new document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

So I want to allow non authenticated users to create documents in a specific collection but not to be able to do anything else (read, update, delete etc.)

When I try adding a new document it is giving me a permission denied error which goes away if I also allow the list permission. How can I add a document without needing to allow the list permission?

Here is the code I'm trying to run:

```
db.doc('/bookings/' + newdocid).set(data).then(function() { console.log('Success!'); });
```

Here is my permission code in firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /bookings/{booking} {
        allow create; // if I move list here it starts working
        allow list, get, read, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you try again without the other permissions and just use `allow create: if true;`